# Standardize child classes with slightly different method signatures

Tags: c#, refactoring, software-design

Iam refactoring a project but finding difficulties.

The goal is to remove some switch cases from the code that are based on the `ServiceType` (see in code).

**Some context**

`ServiceA`, `ServiceB`, etc. are all classes pretty similar that describe different services.
I would like to:

- let them implement an interface (let's say `IService`)
- make a Factory that returns the right concrete (`ServiceXX : IService`)

so that in the end I will be able to reduce the amount of switch cases.

Here a switch that I would like to remove:

```
foreach (Service s in PartnerServices)
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
                
    switch (s.Type)
    {
        case "ServiceA":
            min = ServiceA.GetMinPrice();
            max = ServiceA.GetMaxPrice();
            break;
    
        case "ServiceB":
            min = ServiceB.GetMinPrice();
            max = ServiceB.GetMaxPrice();
            break;
                    
        case "ServiceC":
            min = ServiceC.GetMinPrice();
            max = ServiceC.GetMaxPrice();
            break;

        case "ServiceD":
            min = ServiceD.GetMinPrice(StateID);
            max = ServiceD.GetMaxPrice(StateID);
            break;  
                    
        case "ServiceE":
            min = ServiceE.GetMinPrice(StateID, CustomerID);
            max = ServiceE.GetMaxPrice(StateID, CustomerID);
            break;                       
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem Iam facing is that the majority of `GetMinPrice` and `GetMaxPrice` implementations need 0 parameters, while a few needs parameters.

This is due to the fact that some services need external info to calculate the price (for example `ServiceE`, needs to know the `StateID` and the `CustomerID` cause the price can be customized for that two keys).

So while the classes belong to the same "root" the method signature is different.

How is this usually managed? Do you have any suggestion?

Please consider that I cannot insert these parameters as properties of the relevant Service class because these are external infos and do not belong there.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override a Base Class method and add a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633336/how-to-override-a-base-class-method-and-add-a-parameter)

Comment: You could use three Interfaces and check them in the switch statement. One interface dictates the method without any argument and the other two interfaces would enforce the methods with the arguments. You cannot change the method signatures in inheriting classes.

Comment: Another possibility is to inherit from one interface with one method taking all arguments. The implementing classes can then simply discard the arguments if not needed. That is maybe not the cleanest way, because it does not map exactly to the real world, but will completely remove the switch case.

Comment: @CodeStranger thanks for taking the time to answer.
No, i don't think that it would solve the problem for two reasons:
1) because doing that means creating a whole new method that will not correctly work for polymorphism
2) because if i'd do that, i'll still need to keep the switch case in order to be able to pass the parameter in ServiceE case
I cannot understand how to manage the situation where i need some "info" to use the method but i cannot store them within the instance itself because that data do not belong there..

Answer (score 1):

I might have had an idea that got me closer to the solution...
What if i create a new class that will contain all the potential options needed to calculate the price and then pass it to the methods?

Here a sample of the final code that explain what i mean:

```
public class PriceCalculationOptions
{
     public int StateID { get; set; }
     public int CustomerID { get; set; }
}

public interface IService
{
     int GetMinPrice(PriceCalculationOptions options);
     int GetMaxPrice(PriceCalculationOptions options);
}

public class ServiceA/B/C/D/E : IService 
{
     public int GetMinPrice(PriceCalculationOptions options)
     {
        //custom implementation using options
     }
     
     public int GetMaxPrice(PriceCalculationOptions options)
     {
        //custom implementation using options
     }

}

public class ServiceFactory
{
    public static IService CreateService(string ServiceType)
    {
        switch (ServiceType)
        {
            case "ServiceA":
                return new ServiceA();
                break;
        
            case "ServiceB":
                return new ServiceB();
                break;
                        
            ...                      
        }
    }
}
```

And so the initial foreach which contained the switch case becomes:

```
foreach (Service s in PartnerServices)
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
                
    IService service = ServiceFactory.CreateService(s.Type);
    PriceCalculationOptions priceCalculationOptions = new PriceCalculationOptions()
    {
        StateID=1,
        CustomerID = 20
    };
    
    min = service.GetMinPrice(priceCalculationOptions);
    max = service.GetMaxPrice(priceCalculationOptions);
                
    ...
}
```

What do you guys think? Do you see any downside?
To me it seems that it might work!